# How to prevent plot axis labels from being cropped by pdf exporter

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a graph that has relatively long strings for x-axis ticks. In an effort to make them more readable the ticks have been positioned diagonally. The problem arises when I export the plot to pdf. The left-most x-axis tick is partially cropped out in the resultant pdf:

[image]

How do I prevent this from happening?

Code below:

```
require(ggplot2)

# dataframe
df <- structure(list(month = structure(1:12, .Label = c("Jan 2018 to Dec 2018", 
    "Dec 2017 to Nov 2018", "Nov 2017 to Oct 2018", "Oct 2017 to Sep 2018", 
    "Sep 2017 to Aug 2018", "Aug 2017 to Jul 2018", "Jul 2017 to Jun 2018", 
    "Jun 2017 to May 2018", "May 2017 to Apr 2018", "Apr 2017 to Mar 2018", 
    "Mar 2017 to Feb 2018", "Feb 2017 to Jan 2018"), class = "factor"), 
    foo = c(8351999.07887727, 6755934.13878232, 6707439.054735, 
    5640531.60604089, 4059014.68824595, 7394651.70307085, 9225768.22340488, 
    828450.454864651, 6874948.06712493, 2928892.67439023, 3922518.1308575, 
    5243671.78557441)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

# plot
plot.1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = month, y = foo)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = 'darkorchid4', width = 0.45) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "", x = "", y = "Amount of foo") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    label = scales::unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6, sep = "")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1.2, hjust = 1, 
                                   size = 14),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14))

# export to pdf
pdf(file = 'foo_plot.pdf', width = 10, height = 8)
print(plot.1)
dev.off()
```

Comment: `+ coor_flip()`?

Comment: maybe adjust `theme(plot.margin = unit(...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

```
plot.1 + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 1))
```

Option 2:

```
plot.1 + theme(plot.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 20, unit = "pt"))
```

And there may be more options.